# Treating continuous data as a classification problem by predicting bins or quintiles

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I currently have a model that has several numeric Y or predicted variables

Sample Data:

| Y1 | Y2 | ... | YN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2710 | 0.32 | ... | 31231 |
| 1710 | 0.52 | ... | 51231 |

I am currently using regression (multioutput regression with gradient boosting) to predict the Y variables.

Currently I am not happy with the accuracy and was looking at ways to increase accuracy. I was recommended using [discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#:%7E:text=In%20applied%20mathematics%2C%20discretization%20is,and%20implementation%20on%20digital%20computers.) so I treat Y as bins or quintiles. i.e:

| Y1 | Y2 | ... | YN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 - 3000 | 0.3 - 0.4 | ... | 30000 - 40000 |
| 1000 - 2000 | 0.5 - 0.6 | ... | 51000 - 50000 |

How can I go about doing this? What algorithms or libraries perform this? I am finding online how to [discretize features](https://scikit-learn.org/stable//auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_discretization.html) but not so much the data itself. Do I need to manually shape the trained data into bins and then train on it?

I guess what I'm asking is where to go from here coding wise.

Comment: [This is probably a bad idea.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/615428/247274)

Answer (score 0):

One option is scikit-learn's [KBinsDiscretizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html) which bins continuous data into intervals.